# How would I concatenate this line with a string?

Tags: c#

```
Caliber = Convert.ToInt32(values[(int)TankData.Cannon]); //add measurement here
```

Okay so in my datagridveiw I want to add measurements to columns that need them but every time I try to concatenate this line with a string `Caliber = Convert.ToInt32(values[(int)TankData.Cannon]) + " mm";` I keep getting the error of "Cannont implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Answer (score 0):

Your "Caliber" variable is Integer I believe. Of course, you cannot set a string value to an integer variable.
If you want to add measurement to a column, this could work

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)    
{
            DataGridView.Rows[i]["Caliber"] += " mm";
}
```